# Strange unity quirk with playerprefs?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

So I have what I assume is either a glitch or a quirk of unity that I don't understand. I have the following script:

```
highscore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player score");

Debug.Log("high" + highscore);

GUI.Box(Rect((Screen.width/2 - 150), (Screen.height/2 - 25),300,55),"Welcome to the target range!" + "\nHigh Score: " + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player Score")+ "\nSelect Difficulty:");
```

However, it displays:

```
Welcome to the target range!
High Score: 10
Select Difficulty
```

This would be fine, except the debug log says highscore is a different number (720 to be exact). Does anyone know why this is?

(This isn't a huge issue, as it was solved by replacing the PlayerPrefs in the output with highscores, but I'd still like to know what's going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you're using different keys (note the `S` in `score`):

```
PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player score"); // first this
PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player Score")  // later this
```

The keys are case sensitive, so those two refer to different values.

Comment: To add tho this, keys should almost always be stored as `const string` declarations to avoid errors like this.  The key should never change, and if it does you should change the constant, not everywhere you use the value of the constant.